# IntelliJ 2022 Java functional test failed with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/KotlinNothingValueException

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

The Java functional test uses a package implemented with Kotlin 1.2.  Trace the error,  following Kotlin statement triggered the error. JDK8 is used and the Kotlin package uses kotlin-stdlib 1.2.  but KotlinNothingValueException was only introduced in [Kotlin 1.4](https://forum.devtalk.com/t/kotlin-v1-4-0-released/1411#:%7E:text=introduce%20kotlinnothingvalueexception%20and%20throw%20it%20instead%20of%20npe%20on%20expressions%20of%20type%20nothing), so seems IntelliJ 2022 expects Kotlin 1.4 or higher?

```
private val demoted  = Demoted<D>()
```

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?